# How do I display the overall weighed grade

Tags: c

In C i'm creating a grade system and Im stuck on how to get the weighed grade of homework and tests separately then add them to an overall grade. I get the math for finding the weighted numbers but I don't exactly know how to get the sum of the loop and where to display it.

Homework grades are 5%

Test grades are 10%

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define ID_LEN 10
#define NAME_LEN 21
#define HW_SCORES 10
#define TEST_SCORES 5

typedef struct {
    char id[ID_LEN];
    char fname[NAME_LEN];
    char lname[NAME_LEN];
    char mi;
    unsigned char hw_scores[HW_SCORES];
    unsigned char test_scores[TEST_SCORES];
//modify struct stu_rect_type
} stu_rec_type;

int idcmp(const void *a, const void *b) {

    stu_rec_type *pa = (stu_rec_type *) a;
    stu_rec_type *pb = (stu_rec_type *) b;
    return -(strcmp(pa->id, pb->id));
}
int lnamecmp(const void *a, const void *b) {

    stu_rec_type *pa = (stu_rec_type *) a;
    stu_rec_type *pb = (stu_rec_type *) b;
    return -(strcmp(pa->lname, pb->lname));
}
int scorecmp(const void *a, const void *b) {

    stu_rec_type *pa = (stu_rec_type *) a;
    stu_rec_type *pb = (stu_rec_type *) b;
    int total_a = 0, total_b = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < HW_SCORES; i++) {
            total_a += 0.1*pa->hw_scores[i];
            total_b += 0*1*pb->hw_scores[i];
    }
    for (i=0; i < TEST_SCORES; i++) {
            total_a += 0.05*pa->test_scores[i];
            total_b += 0.05*pb->test_scores[i];
    }
    if (total_a == total_b)
            return strcmp(pa->lname, pb->lname);
        //Sorting in descending order
        else  if(total_a > total_b)
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
}

void print_rec(stu_rec_type *rec_ptr) {
        int j;
        printf("ID: %s\n", rec_ptr->id);
    printf("NAME: %s %c. %s\n", rec_ptr->fname, rec_ptr->mi, rec_ptr->lname );
    printf("HW SCORES:\n");
    for (j=0; j <HW_SCORES; j++){
        printf("%4d", rec_ptr->hw_scores[j]);
        if ( (j+1)%10 ==0)
                printf("\n");
    }
    printf("TEST SCORES:\n");
    for (j=0; j <TEST_SCORES; j++){
        printf("%4d", rec_ptr->test_scores[j]);
        if ( (j+1)%10 ==0)
                printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    //prompt user to input number of students
    int CLASS_SIZE;
    printf("Enter the number of students : ");
    scanf("%d",&CLASS_SIZE);
    stu_rec_type *cs3500_class;
    //malloc to allocate momeory of student records
    // Dynamically allocating memory for an array of student records.
    cs3500_class=(stu_rec_type *)malloc(sizeof(stu_rec_type)*CLASS_SIZE);
    int i, j, k;
    char *ptr;
    stu_rec_type *stu_ptr;
    int n = 700000000;
    char id[10];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < CLASS_SIZE; i++) {
    // generate ids
    //ptr = (char *) &(cs3500_class[i].id);
    // sprintf(ptr, "%i", ++n);
      sprintf((char *)&(cs3500_class[i].id), "%i", ++n);
    // generate the first names
        cs3500_class[i].fname[0] = 'A' + rand()%26;
    k = rand()%(NAME_LEN-1);
    for (j=0; j < k; j++)
        cs3500_class[i].fname[j+1] = 'a' + rand()%26;
        cs3500_class[i].fname[k+1] = '\0';
    // generate the last names
        cs3500_class[i].lname[0] = 'A' + rand()%26;
    k = rand()%(NAME_LEN-1);
    for (j=0; j < k; j++)
        cs3500_class[i].lname[j+1] = 'a' + rand()%26;
        cs3500_class[i].lname[k+1] = '\0';
    // generate mi
        cs3500_class[i].mi = 'A' + rand()%26;
    // generate hw scores between 10-20 max being 20
    for (j=0; j<HW_SCORES; j++)
        cs3500_class[i].hw_scores[j] = (rand() % 10) + 11;
    // generate test scores between 50-100 max being 100
    for (j=0; j<TEST_SCORES; j++)
        cs3500_class[i].test_scores[j] = 51 + (rand()%50);
    }
    // displaying the first 5 records
    for (i = 0; i < CLASS_SIZE; i++) {
            print_rec(&cs3500_class[i]);
    printf("\n\n ");
    }
    // sort the records based on the 1st score
    //using qsort() in descending order
    printf("\n\nAfter qsort\n");
    qsort(cs3500_class, CLASS_SIZE, sizeof(stu_rec_type), scorecmp);
    // display the first 5 records
    for (i = 0; i < CLASS_SIZE; i++) {
        print_rec(&cs3500_class[i]);
    printf("\n\n");
    }
    return 0;
```

This is when I run the code and plan on putting the overall weighted grade after the scores.

[image]

Comment: Homework grades are 5% and Test grades are 10%... what makes up the other 85%?

Answer (score 0):

You want to weigh homework as 5% and test grades as 10% which doesn't make a lot of sense to me... maybe there is something I'm missing.  But if I was to weigh homework as 35% and test grades as 65%, we might be able to do something along these lines...

```
#define HW_MAX 20
#define TEST_MAX 100

typedef struct {
    ...
    int hw_scores[HW_SCORES];
    int test_scores[TEST_SCORES];
    int grade;
} stu_rec_type;

// computes grade on a 0..100 scale
void compute_grade(stu_rec_type *rec_ptr)
{
    float HW_WEIGHT = 0.35;
    float TEST_WEIGHT 0.65;

    float hw_avg = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < HW_SCORES; ++i)
        hw_avg += rec_ptr->hw_scores[i] / HW_MAX;

    hw_avg /= HW_SCORES;

    float test_avg = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < TEST_SCORES; ++i)
        test_avg += rec_ptr->test_scores[i] / TEST_MAX;

    test_avg /= TEST_SCORES;

    rec_ptr->grade = (hw_avg * HW_WEIGHT + test_avg * TEST_WEIGHT) * 100;
}
```